# Express static serves index.html How to deny it?

Tags: node.js, angular, express

When I serve my angular 5 app from node express I face this issue as express static serves index.html when I visit **domain.com** but I when I visit **domain.com/something** it works correctly can some help how do I solve this

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist'))); //This line serves index.html how to deny it

app.use("/api", routes);

app.get('*', function(req, res) { //The reason it needs to be * so that it works with angular routes or it wont work

//This is never called when i visit domain.com. but it does when i visit domain.com/somthing

   console.log("i was serverd"); 
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you want to serve `dist/index.html` in your route and not with `express.static`?

Comment: @vibhor1997a yes correct

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Found a solution**

```
var options = {
  index: false
}

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist'), options));
```

**index**  : Sends the specified directory index file. Set to false to disable directory indexing.

Refer: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround for your prooblem

```
 app.use('/',(req,res,next)=>{
  if(req.path!='/')
    next();
  console.log('ii');
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'dist/index.html'));
},express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

app.get('*',(req,res,next)=>{
  console.log('ii');
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'dist/index.html'));
});
```

This will cover for all your requests. But in this way you would have to write same code in 2 routes

Answer (score 0):

Replace `*` with `/`.

This should be registered before the `app.use(express.static` call. (Thank you [jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816620/jfriend00))

Ex :

```
 app.get('/', function(req, res) { //see, no asterix

    //This is never called when i visit domain.com. but it does when i visit domain.com/somthing

       console.log("i was serverd"); 
       res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
    });

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
```

Comment: You left out an important part that this has to be placed BEFORE the `app.use(express.static(...))` line so the `/` request is handled before it gets to the `express.static()` middleware.

Comment: @Ishan Thilina Somasiri It doesn't work it's not what I asked for.